# Not scrolling to bottom of the page on adding new element

Tags: html, css, angularjs

On adding new element on the last child of my `container' on the time scroll appears. I'd like to scroll-down to put the new element on browser view.

I tried using '$anchorScroll` but that doesn't work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="galleryMenu">
        <!-- <a class="live" ng-click="galleryMenu('live')" href="#">live</a>
        <a class="visual" ng-click="galleryMenu('visual')" href="#">visuals</a> -->
        <a class="projects" ng-click="galleryMenu('projects')" href="#">projects</a> //clicking and calling galleryMenu function
</div>
<!-- Focus needs to be applied here, height of element is 180px -->
<div class="appGallery" ng-show="galleryShow" id="anchor3">
        <a ng-click="galleryChanger('prev')" class="prev" href="#">prev</a>
        <a ng-click="galleryChanger('next')" class="next"  href="#">next</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
"use strict";

angular.module("tcpApp")
    .run(['$anchorScroll', function($anchorScroll) {
        $anchorScroll.yOffset = 180; //running here.
    }])
    .controller("homeController", ['$scope','server', '$anchorScroll', '$location', function ($scope, server, $anchorScroll, $location) {

        $scope.galleryMenu = function (gallery) {

        var newHash = 'anchor3';
        if ($location.hash() !== newHash) {
          $location.hash('anchor3');
        } else {
          $anchorScroll();
        }

    }]);
```

Comment: Aren't you creating many anchors with the same name?

Comment: no, only one i have. this is hardcoded.

Comment: can you make a fiddle???